# Eclipse Java log4j autocomplete too many parameters

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, autocomplete, log4j

There's an annoying issue in Eclipse STS:

Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201712210947
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)

When I use org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger and let Eclipse autocomplete and ask for the parameters, it opens up the largest set of parameters. I.e:

```
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
```

...
I go to type:

```
log.debug(
```

and Eclipse editor autocompletes:

```
log.debug(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9);
```

and it fills out all of those method parameters. 
Previously, not sure which version, it defaulted to the one where I can just pass a message i.e. log.debug(msg) and I can fill out my msg string. 
Anyone have this happen to them too?

PS I know I can select the log.debug(msg) in the menu but it's like 5 deep in the context menu.

Edit: 
this also happens on multiple PCs, and I have re-installed it many times. It's been like this for many months now.

Comment: I've never found a way to configure the various code completion, template suggestions and code recommenders, to this level of detail, in Eclipse.  It's not even clear which of the long list of plugins is responsible.

Comment: Yes - very annoying ...  Wish there were a possibility to overcome this "problem"